# How to have a dynamic DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an observable collection that I am displaying in a Xamarin Forms ListView.  I have defined a detail and a summary template that I use to view each list item.  I want to be able to dynamically change between summary and detail template based on a Boolean property in each item.

Here is the item.

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _switch = false;
    public bool Switch
    {
        get
        {
            return _switch;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_switch != value)
            {
                _switch = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Switch"));
            }
        }

    }
    public int Addend1 { get; set; }
    public int Addend2 { get; set; }
    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return Addend1 + Addend2;
        }
    }
    public string Summary
    {
        get
        {
            return Addend1 + " + " + Addend2 + " = " + Result;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Here is the observable collection.  Note that whenever the switch value changes I remove the item and reinsert.  The reason this is done is to force the ListView to reselect the DataTemplate.

```
public class MyItems : ObservableCollection<MyItem>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, MyItem item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += MyItems_PropertyChanged;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this[index].PropertyChanged -= MyItems_PropertyChanged;
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }
    private void MyItems_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = IndexOf(sender as MyItem);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            RemoveAt(index);
            Insert(index, sender as MyItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my data template selector...

```
public class MyItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    DataTemplate Detail { get; set; }
    DataTemplate Summary { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if(item is MyItem)
        {
            return (item as MyItem).Switch ? Detail : Summary;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here are my resource definitions...

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDetail">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Switch}"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Addend1}"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Addend2}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Result}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MySummary">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Switch}"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Summary}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyItemTemplateSelector x:Key="MySelector" Detail="{StaticResource MyDetail}" Summary="{StaticResource MySummary}"/>
```

Here is my collection initialization...

```
        MyItems = new MyItems();
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = true, Addend1 = 1, Addend2 = 2 });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = false, Addend1 = 1, Addend2 = 2 });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = true, Addend1 = 2, Addend2 = 3 });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = false, Addend1 = 2, Addend2 = 3 });
```

And this is what it looks like...

[image]

Right.  So everything works fine. If the switch is toggled the view of the item changes from summary to detail.  The problem is that this cannot be the right way of doing this!  It is a complete kluge to remove a list item and put it back in the same place in order to get the data template to reselect.  But I cannot figure out another way of doing it.  In WPF I used a data trigger in an item container style to set the content template based on the switch value, but there seems to be no way to do the equivalent thing in Xamarin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is not through switching templates, but defining a content view as the template and changing the visibility of controls within the template.  There is apparently no way to get the ListView to re-evaluate the item template on an item short of removing it and re-adding it.

Here is my content view...

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsBench"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsBench.SummaryDetailView">
<ContentView.Content>
  <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Switch x:Name="toggle" IsToggled="{Binding Switch}"/>
        <Entry x:Name="addend1" Text="{Binding Addend1}"/>
        <Entry x:Name="addend2" Text="{Binding Addend2}"/>
        <Label x:Name="result" Text="{Binding Result}"/>
        <Label x:Name="summary" Text="{Binding Summary}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

This is the code behind...

```
namespace XamarinFormsBench
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SummaryDetailView : ContentView
{
    public SummaryDetailView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toggle.PropertyChanged += Toggle_PropertyChanged;
        UpdateVisibility();
    }

    private void Toggle_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "IsToggled")
        {
            UpdateVisibility();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateVisibility()
    {
        bool isDetail = toggle.IsToggled;
        addend1.IsVisible = isDetail;
        addend2.IsVisible = isDetail;
        result.IsVisible = isDetail;
        summary.IsVisible = !isDetail;
        InvalidateLayout();  // this is key!
    }
}
}
```

Now the main page contains this...

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <local:SummaryDetailView/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The key to making this work properly is to invalidate the layout of the ContentView when switching between summary and detail.  This forces the ListView to layout the cell again.  Without this the controls that are made invisible disappear the controls made visible never show.  You do not need this if the ContentView is used outside of the ListView.  This seems to me to be a bug in the ListView.  You could get the item template switching to work if you could invalidate the layout of the ViewCell, but there is no public method (only a protected one) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This was tricky issue for me few years ago. I've came to MarkupExtensions and converters (IValueConverter). After heavy struggle with XAML extensions realm I've figured an obvious thing: it shouldn't be done like that.

For dynamic change of (m)any property(ies) of the component you should use Styles. Reactions of property (it has to be DependencyProperty to work with components) changes are simple to set via Stryle.Triggers and Setters.

```
<Style x:Key="imbXmlTreeView_itemstyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-23,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Panel.Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource fade_lightGray}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource fade_darkGray}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource fade_lightGray}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource fade_darkGray}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Consider above (just copied from my old project): DynamicResource can be your DataTemplate.

Here is more accurate example you might use:

```
<Style x:Key="executionFlowBorder" TargetType="ContentControl" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Border Style="{DynamicResource executionBorder}" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=isExecuting}" Content="" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=displayName, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="10" Grid.Column="1" FontStretch="Expanded"  FontWeight="Black"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=iconSource, Mode=OneWay}" Width="16" Height="16" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=displayComment, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Where the value of setter can be DynamicResource or one delivered via your MarkupExtension - some thing like I had here:

```
using System; 
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Markup;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Pristup glavnom registru resursa
    /// </summary>
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof (ResourceDictionary))]
    public class masterResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public masterResourceExtension()
        {
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            try
            {
                return imbXamlResourceManager.current.masterResourceDictionary;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The MarkupExtensions you are using as in example below:
In the XAML code:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Name="image_splash" Source="{imb:imbImageSource ImageName=splash}" Stretch="Fill" />
```

---

**Added later:** just don't forget to add namespace/assembly reference (pointing to the code with the custom MarkupExtension) at top of the XAML Window/Control (in this example it is **imbCore.xaml** from separate library project of the same solution):

```
<Window x:Class="imbAPI.imbDialogs.imbSplash"
        xmlns:imb="clr-namespace:imbCore.xaml;assembly=imbCore"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Path=splashTitle}" Height="666" Width="896" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Topmost="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        xmlns:imbControls="clr-namespace:imbAPI.imbControls">
    <Grid>
```

Also have in mind you have to compile it first in order to get it working in XAML designer.

---

The C# code of the extension used:

```
 using System; 
    using System.Windows.Markup;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using imbCore.resources;

    #endregion

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof (ImageSource))]
    public class imbImageSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public imbImageSourceExtension()
        {
        }

        public imbImageSourceExtension(String imageName)
        {
            this.ImageName = imageName;
        }

        [ConstructorArgument("imageName")]
        public String ImageName { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            try
            {

                if (imbCoreApplicationSettings.doDisableIconWorks) return null;
                return imbIconWorks.getIconSource(ImageName);

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope I got your question right on the first place :).
Now I have to sleap :). Good luck!

Added later: ok, I missed your point :) sorry. However, I would leave the response in case you find something useful in the codes I've posted. Bye!

Comment: I think this all works in WPF not in Xamarin Forms.  What I have discovered about Xamarin Forms is that only the most basic stuff from WPF works.